# BASE DE DATOS AGREGADA EN INSTALADOR DE VISUAL STUDIO 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Quisiera saber ¿como podría añadir mi base de datos en un instalador que estoy creando en visual studio 2017?, para que al ejecutarlo mi instalador en cualquier maquina mi programa corra de manera normal.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta debe dar mas informacion, por ejemplo que base de datos, y como construis tu instalador

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que utilices una base de datos como SQLite.La cual es una base de datos, es un simple archivo.

De igual manera puedes tener tus consultas sql. Este archivo lo puedes integrar dentro de tu resource de tu aplicación, y al instalarlo traerá la base de datos..

Utilizar SQL Server se utiliza mas comúnmente cuando las aplicaciones no se van a conectar de manera local, es decir.. tu aplicación estará en una maquina pero se conectará a un servidor en su red o en la nube, para compartir esos datos con otros clientes.